# In java code search helper to find all places where braces is missing

Tags: java, android, android-studio, braces

Lets say I have a bunch of code and all the braces are gone like

```
Look no braces:
if(condition)
  statement;

Yes java code convention using braces
if(condition)
{
  statement;
}
```

In particularly for Android Studio would be nice if there was a e.g. Lint check maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix this in the android studio settings:

Settings → Editor → Code Style → Java → 'if()' statement.

Then set *Force braces* to *Always*.
After that, you can run <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to format the current file to the right conventions.

if you want to format all the files in a directory simply:
*right click* on the folder → *Reformat code*

Comment: Thanks I guess that answer the question. I have 300 source files :)